# how to design this UI in android

Tags: android, user-interface

i want to show a UI as like the following image[image]

how to show the horizontal and vertical lines between those numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See how the lines between the boxes cast shadows? and there is a shine that carries across sections?  It looks to me like the that is just a background image with the numbers laid over top of it in certain positions.  So do a Relative Layout with a background image.